# VB Script - Backup Win 7 Profiles

Tags: windows, vbscript

I am trying to create a VBScript in order to backup Windows 7 profiles when replacing PC's.

Currently I have:

```
Option Explicit

Const SHARENAME = "c:\NHSITTemp"

Dim fldr,subfldr
Dim sUser
Dim shl, fso

Set shl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")

'this gets 'Documents and Settings'
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder( _
                Replace(shl.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%"), _
                shl.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%"), _
                ""))
'for each folder in fldr
For Each subfldr In fldr.SubFolders
  If fso.FolderExists(subfldr.Path & "\Desktop") Then
    sUser = subfldr.Name
    if not fso.FolderExists(SHARENAME & "\" & sUser) Then
      Call fso.CreateFolder(SHARENAME & "\" & sUser)
    End If
    Call fso.CopyFolder(subfldr.Path & "\Desktop", _
                        SHARENAME & "\" & sUser & "\Desktop")
  End If
Next

Set fso = Nothing
Set shl = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

This is generating errors on line 13 which I cannot figure out, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

```
Option Explicit

Const SHARENAME = "c:\NHSITTemp"

Dim fldr,subfldr
Dim sUser
Dim shl, fso

Set shl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")

'this gets 'Documents and Settings'
 Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(Replace(Replace(_
            shl.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%"),_
            shl.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%"),""), "\\", ""))
'for each folder in fldr
For Each subfldr In fldr.SubFolders
  If fso.FolderExists(subfldr.Path & "\Desktop") Then
    sUser = subfldr.Name
    if not fso.FolderExists(SHARENAME & "\" & sUser) Then
           fso.CreateFolder SHARENAME & "\" & sUser
    End If
    fso.CopyFolder subfldr.Path & "\Desktop", SHARENAME & "\" & sUser & "\Desktop"
  End If
Next

Set fso = Nothing
Set shl = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Running it locally, Windows Script Host error on line 13 - Path not found.

Also the revised code you posted generated an error on line 24 - Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub?

Comment: I've updated the code above to show removal of parenthesis, you should try to activate a `msgbox shl.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")` command before executing the getfolder command. Also, are you running the script remotely?

Comment: No running it directly from the C: drive. 

Your revised code is back to the original error of Path not found on line 13?

Comment: Ok, so your expandenvironmentstrings returned "FolderName\\" The double back-slashes at the end cause get folder to seek nested folders and therfore failed. Try out the revised code above when you get a chance. Thanks!

Comment: Still getting a runtime error on line 13, path not found??